# Watir equivalent to Capybara.server_port?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, capybara, watir, watir-webdriver

Is it possible to change a Watir Browser object's server port?

I'm looking for something in Watir or Watir-webdriver (or Selenium-webdriver, even) akin to what you get with `Capybara.server_port` (when you're using Capybara, obviously)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm not mistaken then should be like

```
require "selenium-webdriver"

profile = Selenium::WebDriver::Firefox::Profile.new
profile['network.proxy.http'] = 'localhost'
profile['port']=9095

driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :firefox, :profile => profile
```

Comment: Thanks. I'll accept your answer if no Watir gurus come along and speak up in the next couple days.